# How do i make my website inaccesible from public?

Tags: html, css, database

i want to make a website that will not be accessed by anyone, there will be a login page in which you can't make an account, only for admins.

for example, i have a homepage which will be on `example.com/homepage`, if normal people accessed this they wouldn't be able to see it and instead get redirected to `example.com/login` unless they login with the right account they won't be able to go to the other sections of the websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by configuring your web server. E.g. Apache has multiple choices, the simplest one being with just two files https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking

For more complicated solutions you'll need a server side programming language, like PHP.

Comment: thanks! can i do this without using php? and why is php the best language for this project?

Comment: You can do without PHP, even without any server side programming language - see the first paragraph of my answer.

I wasn't saying PHP was the best language, just one of the options.